# Searching the entire window object in Browser for value

Tags: javascript, templates, object, browser, window

So i have a project here scraping several websites

The object that i need is in definitely in the window object as JSON as they are using templates and client-side rendering

however searching through each variable in the window object is a pain and annoying and can waist so much time

I was wondering if anyone knows of a function/method i can use to search for a key value through the entire window object as i have run into many roadblocks with this my self and it is not like i can just stingify the whole window object and console.log it